# Insert Table On Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering if there is a better or easy way for user to insert a `table` on a `<textarea>`. One of the solution that I found is to have a *WYSIWYG* editor. For example, **[CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)** or **[TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/)**.

I have a form for user to submit a Purchase Order. It has a `<textarea>` to input details regarding the purchase and I would like to make user to have the option to insert the details on a table format. eg:

```
Item | Price  | Supplier Name
1    | $900   | Samsung 
2    | $1000  | Iphone
```

Any ideas on how can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean something like excel? Google sheets?

Comment: Why a textarea? Why not [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) or [Kendo UI Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index)? If you want tabular input I think it's a better way to do it.

Comment: Just a simple table to display the details. The table can be done on the `textarea`. Something like `<table><tr><th>Item</th><th>Price</th><th>Supplier</th></tr></table>`

Comment: You can't put HTML in a textarea to be rendered as HTML

Comment: Thanks for the idea @jorgonor. Do we need to pay to use both of the functions?

Comment: @Amran I'm unsure if DataTables Editor is now free, in the past you had to pay for sure, but I can't tell 100%. [Kendo UI Core](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core) is free while it has several components like this grid. Have a look yourself and look what suits better to your use case.

Comment: @j08691 is there other way to achieve it?

Comment: You could always use a markdown editor instead of WYSIWYG...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @moopet. Just to reconfirm, is it similar to stackoverflow?

Comment: Markdown? Yes, same sort of thing. Make a table with pipes as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help